# Бэкграунд с засечками

Tags: html, css

Всем здравствуйте!

Знаю, что это можно сделать как-то просто. Давно делал, забыл как делал. Напомните, пожалуйста, как можно сделать фон с такими повторяющимеся засечками?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/CyberAP/eSx3d/), к примеру. Можно обойтись без картинки.

```css
html { height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; text-align: center; }
body:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 120px;
    width: 75%;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-width: 10px 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);
    background-image:
        -webkit-linear-gradient(lightblue, skyblue),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, transparent 50.5%, lightblue 50.5%),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, transparent 50.5%, lightblue 50.5%),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom left, transparent 50.5%, skyblue 50.5%),
        -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right, transparent 50.5%, skyblue 50.5%);
    background-image:
        -moz-linear-gradient(lightblue, skyblue),
        -moz-linear-gradient(top left, transparent 50.5%, lightblue 50.5%),
        -moz-linear-gradient(top right, transparent 50.5%, lightblue 50.5%),
        -moz-linear-gradient(bottom left, transparent 50.5%, skyblue 50.5%),
        -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, transparent 50.5%, skyblue 50.5%);
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(lightblue, skyblue),
        linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50.5%, lightblue 50.5%),
        linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 50.5%, lightblue 50.5%),
        linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50.5%, skyblue 50.5%),
        linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50.5%, skyblue 50.5%);
    background-repeat: repeat, repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 0, 10px 0, 10px 0, 10px 100%, 10px 100%;
    background-size: auto auto, 20px 20px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;
    background-clip: padding-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box, border-box, border-box, border-box, border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>Синий заборик</div>
```

Comment: Я так и не понял... А что же создает засечки?

Comment: @Zelta черная архимагия как ни странно

Answer (score 0):

Ответ банален: [берешь и делаешь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/background). Обратите внимание на пример 1: в вашем случае будет repeat-x. Если начнутся проблемы с горизонтальным стыковком текстур — нужно принять какое-то дизайнерское решение, например, сделать линию в месте стыка.

Comment: А если это надо с двух сторон?

Comment: можно наложить несколько фонов. это описано во 2-м примере.

Comment: А, да, забыл: для экономии трафика я бы рекомендовал сделать текстуру из всего одного треугольника.

Comment: Спасибо за консультацию!